# Which is correct: 'Drafty' or 'draughty'?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, british-english, adjectives

I have been changing 'drafty' for 'draughty', or because of my confusion, removing the word altogether while subbing online articles.

I'd appreciate guidance on which term is correct for UK English.

Answer (score 9):

*Draft* is principally an American English variant that, like many other such simplified spellings, has entered the British English lexicon as an increasingly acceptable alternative spelling. *Draft* is also considered the standard British English spelling for certain definitions such as a technical drawing, a preliminary or rough version, or the act or result of "drawing" from or upon something (e.g. a Military Draft.)

*Draughty* is preferable for British English as this is the more common spelling when referring to a current of air.

Comment: Is it pronounced the same? I'm not seeing an F sound in there.

Comment: Yes, it's the same - as in "laugh."

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely subjective, and coming from a BritEng, but I see these differences:

- Draft I would use for being taken into military service, for a preliminary drawing.
- Draughts I would use for the game (that's checkers for AmEng, I believe)
- For the windy variety, I'd be comfortable with either.

[Wikipedia seems to agree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_and_draft#Miscellaneous_spelling_differences), and has more detail.

Answer (score 0):

[The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/draughty) says

> draughty US, drafty

and

> drafty [ˈdrɑːftɪ]
> ...
>
> the usual US spelling of draughty

Answer (score 0):

I would always use 'draughty' myself for the currents of cold air definition - like you I've been wrong-footed by the spelling checker online many times! I think it's extraordinary that despite our region there is no option for an English language setting as opposed to American.

Comment: For any decent browser you can add spelling dictionaries in any language of your choice. It's possible you may need the to be available as an operating system language but that's no problem either.

Answer (score -1):

I’m American, I spell it drafty.  My American husband grew up reading much British literature and spells it draughty. He didn’t know that his version is odd until I noticed the difference in closed captioning of a British TV show and brought it to his attention. He pronounces things British also from watching BBC TV as a child.
We grew up in the 1970s, before cable TV and we’re nerdy. So, rural isolation without media other than public television and science fiction stories lead to an isolated pocket of British dialect for him. Otherwise, thanks to Noah Webster and his ‘We aren’t owned by England anymore’ dictionary of American English, we Yankees use variant spellings of words using fewer letters than the British originals.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please edit your answer to answer the question on which spelling is correct for UK English.